# Remove space that has come after transforming

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pdf, react-to-pdf

I want to generate a pdf of the layout. There will a fixed size for a div eg. The width of the div 720px and I want to maintain it 720 on all the devices. Since the div will go outside the screen on mobile devices I used to transform(scale) to make it small size but there is space below the div. I want to remove that space. below is the code for your reference.

```css
.Scale {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.blue { 
  background: blue; 
}

.red{ 
  background: red; 
}

.Scale div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.Scale {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="Scale">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: transform is only a visual effect and doesn't affect the layout

Comment: I posted a code as an answer to see if that is what you are looking for. Please check and vote if it solves your issue.

Comment: @sina_rosemann no need to add such comment, the OP is notified when an answer is posted

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that is great to know!

Answer (score 1):

it's simple
you have to calculate with height,
If for some reason you turn it upside down! like here your current **width: 500px;** and **height: 220px;** you want to reverse it like **width: 220px; height: 500px;**
then again you have to use **margin-bottom: calc((0.6 - 1) * 500px);** that's it.

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 5px solid #337326;
}

#child {
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
  background: #555; 
  transform: scale(0.6);
  transform-origin: top center;
  margin-bottom: calc((0.6 - 1) * 220px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if thats what you are asking for but if you use ScaleX instead the space below is gone as you are only scaling on the X-axis.

Try the code below:

```css
.Scale {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.blue { 
  background: blue; 
}

.red{ 
  background: red; 
}

.Scale div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.Scale {
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="Scale">
              <div class="red"></div>
              <div class="blue"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a "space below the div" because your `<div class="parent">` is not being scaled down, thus its `1px border` will remain in the same position. At the same time you have scaled down the `<div class="Scale">` and it is now smaller than the parent, whose border is visible.

To *"remove"* the white space below the scaled div, you should also scale the parent down by adding the class `.Scale` to it like so:

```html
<div class="parent Scale">
  <div class="Scale">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also for cleaner code, group the `.Scaled` class together in your css.

```
.Scale {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.blue { 
  background: blue; 
}

.red{ 
  background: red; 
}

.Scale div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Hope it helps!